# Проверка на прошедшее время

Tags: php

Допустим, у нас есть переменная $a, где записана дата 22.01.2012 (дата может меняться). Нам нужно выполнить скрипт только при условии, если прошел месяц. Как такое сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

тут надо превратить обе даты в метки времени(начиная от 1 января 1970года), используя функцию

```
> int mktime ( [int hour [, int minute[, int second [, int month [, int day
> [, int year [, int is_dst]]]]]]] )
```

Эта функция возвращает кол-во секунд, прошедшее с 1 января 1970 года. Думаю, далее ты и сам справишься =)
Потом просто надо превратить обе даты в метки и сравнить, что больше...

Answer (score 2):

Как начинающему, попробуйте поиграться с вот этим:

```
<?php
    //предварительно сохраненное значение предыдущего запуска
    $prevStart = date('U', strtotime("-31 days"));
    //или
    //$prevStart = mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 22, 2011);//главное не путать аргументы
    //собственно оффсет, который необходимо выдержать до следующего запуска
    $monthAgo = date('U', strtotime("-1 month"));
    //проверочка, так как время неумолимо растет, предыдущее значение должно быть меньше нашего оффсета в рассчете на сегодняшний день
    if($prevStart <= $monthAgo)
        //оказывается скрипт не запускался уже месяц
        //сохраняем текущее время запуска и пускаем скрипт
        echo "blabla";
    else
        //можно вообще ничего не делать
        echo "no blabla";
```